# fields_for form builder object is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formbuilder

Any way to access a nested form_bulder.object?

```
## controller
@project = Project.new
@project.tasks.build

form_for(@project) do |f|
  f.object.nil? ## returns false

  fields_for :tasks do |builder|
    builder.object.nil? ## returns true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You must have accepts_nested_attributes_for in the Project model in order for the object to be passed.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks ## this is required
end
```

Comment: Banged my head on this for about 90 minutes. Whew.

Comment: About every 6 month i forget to add this, so annoying that there is no sensible error for this. But i guess it might be hard to detect automatically.

Comment: Saved hours of my time - my gratitude is yours.  Let this be a lesson to my team while doing some heavy refactoring/cleaning of some old and messy model. (ok...it was me,)

Answer (score 18):

`fields_for` requires that the method `tasks_attributes=` exists. `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks` creates this method for you, but you can also just define it yourself:

```
def tasks_attributes=(params)
  # ... manually apply attributes in params to tasks
end
```

When this method does not exist, the `builder.object` ends up being nil.