# Rails FormBuilderInstance.object properties

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, fields-for, formbuilder

I'm working on a rentals system. I have a model called `check_outs` which is a child of a rental     `order` where an order `has_many :check_outs` and a check_out `belongs_to :rental`. My order `accepts_nested_attributes_for :check_outs` and I have a nested `fields_for :check_outs`. I'm using rbates' nested_form gem.

What I'm trying to do is get a property of the rental (description, an attr_accessor of check_outs), that was set in the checkout creation step, to populate a label or text field in the edit view.

I know I can get the check_out object it self using `builder.object` and I can even get `builder.object.rental` but when I try to get `builder.object.rental.id` or `builder.object.rental.description` I get an unknown attribute for nil error. This doesn't seem to make sense since the object itself is not nil.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand what you are doing properly, this should help:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409638/fields-for-form-builder-object-is-nil][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409638/fields-for-form-builder-object-is-nil

Comment: Both of the components in that post's solution are handled in my application. Additionally, that post doesn't really pertain to my problem.

Comment: Any progress on this? Having the same issue with Rails 4.